# how to build a comment tree using neo4j and PHP

Tags: php, neo4j

I want to build a comment tree using neo4j and PHP for example:

```
A
|_B
...|_C
...|_D
```

I am using https://github.com/jadell/neo4jphp component. It doesnt heve this method. Anyway I dont know how to get all tree using Cypher.

Comment: what did you tried? where is the question? for php components you can take a look here : https://github.com/neoxygen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just add comments onto other comments, you can execute this cypher with neo4jphp or neoclient.

```
MATCH (c:Comment {id:{comment_id}})
MATCH (a:Author {id:{author_id}})
CREATE (n:Comment {id:{new_comment_id}, text:{new_comment_text})
CREATE (a)-[:WROTE]->(n)
```